# Is it possible to compare and assign an unsigned char to an integer

Tags: c

Variables `T`, `max_gray` and `qtd_px` are always greater than 0, and `numeros_px` is an `unsigned char` vector that stores values from 0-255.
If it's possible, please explain why, because it seems to work fine here in CodeBlocks, but it doesn't make sense for me, because they are from different types: one is `unsigned char` and the other one is `int`.

```
void filtro(unsigned char *numeros_px, int qtd_px, int T, int max_gray){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<qtd_px; i++){
        if(numeros_px[i]>= T) numeros_px[i]=max_gray;
        else numeros_px[i]=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I was thinking Algol 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can assign char to int, because char is 8 bit wide, integer is 32 (depends on the architecture but on PCs, and 32 bit ARMs, it is 32 bit wide. 16 bit on some chips)

What you can not do is the oppsite as obviously you might loose data.
**In your code this is bad : ** `numeros_px[i]=max_gray;` as `max_grey` is 32 bits and you put it into an 8 bit variable. This is not a problem if `max_grey` is <255

Comment: if both are ints it will work (basically if one is int, your compiler will implicitly cast before to compare).

Comment: But if i attribute: numeros_px[i]=256, numeros_px[i] will not store 256, it will store 255 because it will lose one bit, right?

Comment: Yes, you can compare, but indeed storing here is wrong, I was just typing that :)

Comment: @RoniCésardeCastro: actually in your example the value `0` will be stored. Your value will loose the *highest* bits when casted to a smaller variable.

Comment: I think you want "... if `max_grey is <= 255`".